# Data from another UITableViewCell is repeated in current cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When my custom UITableViewCell is reused, all of the data does not get reset for the current cell. Data from the reused cell is inserted for a particular UILabel.

I have a tableview of Dishes. Dishes have Comments. I'd like to display comments for each dish within a tableviewcell. Depending on how many comments there are, I only make that many comment labels in each cell. However, when a cell is reused, the wrong comment - a comment from a different Dish - shows up.

I am using CoreData and a Dish has many Comments and let's just say I only want to display the first two comments.

I have created two UILabels in IB with heights and width of zero so that it resizes to how long each comment is.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    DishCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DishCell"];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ ...I put all of the Dishes in a NSFetchedResultsController instance so *dish is a NSManagedObject that has many comments

      NSSet *commentsSet = dish.comments;
      NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"date"  ascending:YES];
      NSArray *commentArray = [commentsSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByDate]];

     if (commentsSet.count< 1) {
        dishCell.comment1label.text = @"";
        dishCell.comment2label.text = @"";
     }else {

    Comment *comment = [commentArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *commenterName = comment.displayName;
    NSString *commentString = comment.commentText;
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", commenterName, commentString];

    CGSize comment1Size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constraint.width - dishCell.commentBubble.frame.size.width + 4, constraint.height) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    //Ignore this setFrame - it works
    [dishCell.comment1label setFrame:CGRectMake(32, faveIconYpos - 2 + dishCell.favIcon.frame.size.height, 298 - dishCell.commentBubble.frame.size.width, comment1Size.height + 2)];

    dishCell.text = text;

    if (commentsSet.count > 1) {
        Comment *comment2 = [commentArray objectAtIndex:1];
        [dishCell.comment2label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [dishCell.comment2label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];

        NSString *text2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", comment2.displayName, comment2.commentText];

        CGSize comment2Size = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constraint.width - dishCell.commentBubble.frame.size.width + 4, constraint.height) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [dishCell.comment2label setFrame:CGRectMake(32, faveIconYpos + dishCell.favIcon.frame.size.height + dishCell.testcom.frame.size.height - 2, 298 - dishCell.commentBubble.frame.size.width, comment2Size.height + 2)];
        dishCell.comment2label.text = text2; 
    }
```

I've parsed out some of the code, but the main thing is that data from another cell gets inserted into my labels. Why is this happening?

Comment: I notice that if `commentsSet.count == 1` then `comment2label` is not cleared or otherwise modified.  Should I assume you're using the index path somewhere as a way of choosing which dish matches the current cell?

Comment: Phillip - I do use index path to get the specific Dish. I have tried: dishCell.comment2Label.text = @"" when commentsSet.count == 1, this works, but it just adds a blank label which I then set its frame to CGRectZero - this works, but seems very hacky - is this just the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: When you get a cell to re-use it's going to have whatever was put there last time you used it.  If you don't want it there, you need to change it.  Quote from the docs: "The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell."

Comment: I suppose you could set it hidden if you don't want to use it but then you'd have to be sure to un-hide it when you **did** need it.